# Angular textarea count rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, row, counter

I have a textarea and i want to count the rows and price each row and then add amount to Stripe checkout.

```
<textarea id="textarea-1" rows="15" maxlenght="540" placeholder="Type or paste text here">
</textarea>
```

Input

```
Hello World! 

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
condimentum metus eget facilisis convallis. Nam facilisis magna quis
pretium ultricies.
```

Count/output in script

```
Hello World!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons
ectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam
condimentum metus eget facilisis
convallis. Nam facilisis magnaqu
is pretium ultricies.
```

Row count should be 7.

```
var flatFee = '70.00';
var perRow = '10.00';

function rowController() {

  //Textarea as string
  var text = document.getElementById("textarea").value;

  //Split string into array with 32 characters in each
  var rowSplit = text.val().split("\n", 32);
    //Count arrays (7)
    console.log(rowSplit.length);
}
  //Take string array
  var rows = rowSplit.length(this.value);

  //Counted arrays and add value
  var additionalFees=0;
    if (count.rows > 2) {
      additionalFees = perRow * (count.rows - 2);
  } 

  var amount = parseFloat(flatFee) + parseFloat(additionalFees);

  console.log(amount);
```

The final amount should be able to put in stripe variable amount. Thats the general idea anyways. Console is there to see if it counts.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your JS code?

Comment: `$scope.textAreaModel.split(/[\r\n]/g)`

Comment: Ill get up the js soon but i wanna try some more. Trying to limit character 32 per line with max 15 lines. Cant even do that right cus you can resize window and hold down key to get well over the limit.. running around in a circle